# Why does my cypher query terminate early when using WITH *?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dsl

I have a (relatively) nontrivial cypher query, but I have reduced it down to a small example that still breaks:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("MyIndexName", "'" + "My Search Phrase" + "'~0.8")
YIELD node
WITH *, collect(node) as nodes
RETURN nodes
```

The problem is that when nodes is an empty list (search returned no results) the rest of my query does not execute (returns nothing) when I include a `with *`. In my actual query, I obviously have other variables that would be pulled in by the wildcard.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: If you remove the `WITH` and replace the last two lines with `RETURN *` do you get anything back?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case for the Neo4j subqueries. On an empty db, this works:

```
WITH 'foo' AS foo
CALL {
        CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("titlesAndDescriptions", "matrix") YIELD node
        RETURN COALESCE(COLLECT(node),[]) AS nodes
     }
WITH *,nodes
RETURN *
```

which returns

[image]